# refreshing the contents of a webpage

Tags: php, html

I am trying to retrieve the contents from database table and display them by using a php script. I successfully retrieved and displayed the contents and used meta tag for refreshing the contents for every 5 seconds. Still the page is not refreshing. can you guys help me with this. Here I am attaching my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-eqiv="refresh" content="2">
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","oracle");
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from message order by timestamp DESC");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<font color='red'><b><i>" .$row['2']."
</i></b></font> &nbsp;says:             <font color='green'><b><i>" 
. $row['0']. "</i></b></font>&nbsp;at:" . 
$row['1']. "<br>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might also want to read some documentation on `session_start()`.

Comment: you may also look at AJAX. You dont have to refresh the whole page with ajax, but just the block of the page you need

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code:

```
http-equiv="refresh"
```